# Entity field iteration in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I got many duplicate source code in my views for showing my entity. Actually the code just for showing entity field. For example :

```
//...

<li>{{ entity.code }}</li>
<li>{{ entity.name }}</li>
<li>{{ entity.createdAt|date('d-m-Y H:i:s') }}</li>
<li>{{ entity.updatedAt|date('d-m-Y H:i:s') }}</li>
<li>{{ entity.operator }}</li>

//...
```

I'm thinking to make iteration in Twig without define the object one by one kind of like this :

```
{% for key, field in entity %}
<li>{{ field[key] }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Is that possible to do that in Twig? Or that is just bad practices must avoided and there is best practice to do this things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a twig function or filter and then use either get_class_methods or get_class_vars

then you can do

```
{% set vars = getClassVars(entity) %}
{% for x in vars %}
  <li>{{ attribute(entity, x) }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html
http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php